# Google Apps user's externalIDs

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [externalIDs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) fields for all of our organization's users.

Right now, no user has an externalID.  Is it possible to update a user's externalID information from the admin console, and give new users that same information when they are created individually through the admin console (using [these](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33310) procedures)?

Thank you!

Comment: In admin console, for existing users, click on the user(to whom you want to edit)->userdetails->click on Account->click on edit Basic information->click on Additional Info( Here you can give employee ID/external ID). For new users, while adding a user, click on Additional Info.

Comment: I know this has been a long time, but I have the same question, and don't see the options @SGC lists. Does anyone have an update?

Answer (score 0):

The external Ids and other custom user fields do not appear in the Google Workspace admin, but they can be found in 'Manage your Google Account' for each user (admins would have to login as the user to see them).
Follow this path

- Manage your Google Account
- Data and privacy
- Under Info you can share with others
- Profile Your info and who can see it
- Organization info, See organization info
- Contact info (the external IDs and other custom fields are found here)

It appears that these can only be edited via script

Hope this helps